# Delete from table2 if exists in table1

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 table. table1 have 2 million records and table2 have 11 million record i want to delete table1 from table2   how i do this in MySQL and for this count of data how much that take?
thank you.

Comment: Start your sentences with a cap letter, don't forget commas, period, and any sign that can make you more readable. Don't take it personally, it's just that for me your question is really, really difficult to understand.

Comment: 2 million :O did you hacked some phone company or what? and btw didnt understood your question, and if you want to delete all no's from table 2 simply use the delete query, `DELETE from table2;`

Comment: @Mr.Alien 2 million rows isn't too much if you're working with real applications.

Comment: @NullUserException I wonder... :D

Comment: @Mr.Alien Stack Overflow for example has about about 12 million answers, and probably hundreds of millions of comments.

Comment: @Mr.Alien  exactly. for example in table 1 i have 10 black numbers  and in table2 i have 40 numbers now i want to delete that 10 black list numbers from 40 numbers ....

Comment: oh you want to delete common phone nos? , I guess you got a whole lot of answers//

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are wanting to delete all records in table 2 that match a record in table 1. If so, you could use a subquery. I'm not sure about how efficient this would be with the number of records you have, but the following should work:

```
DELETE FROM table2 where table2.phonenumber IN (select phonenumber from table1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Table2.* FROM Table2   JOIN Table1 ON Table2.phone = Table1.phone WHERE Table2.phone is not null

DELETE Table2.* FROM Table2   JOIN Table1 ON Table2.phone = Table1.phone WHERE Table2.phone is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Delete from table2
where number in (Select number from table1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a join then deleting from the join

```
SELECT tbl1.MyId FROM table1 tbl1
JOIN table2 on tbl1.phonenumber = tb2.phonenumber
```

Then delete from that

Such as

```
DELETE FROM Table2 WHERE MyID IN
(SELECT tbl1.MyId FROM table1 tbl1
JOIN table2 on tbl1.phonenumber = tb2.phonenumber)
```

This is sql code, not exactly sure what changes in mysql

Good luck!

Comment: I am sure there is a more efficient way to do this, but it is the first I came up with.